# Поочередное срабатывание setTimeout в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

У меня есть следующий код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var status = $('#loading-banner h1');
    if(!status) return false;
    setTimeout(function(){
        status.html('Авторизация в системе...');
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        status.html('Получение информации...');
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loading-banner').fadeOut(1000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Если его выполнить, спустя 5 секунд сработает fadeOut(), соответственно функции, передаваемые setTimeout, срабатывают асинхронно. Если ли способ сделать так, чтобы эти функции выполнялись последовательно (то есть fadeOut() должна сработать спустя 15 секунд с момента загрузки документа) без использования множества вложенных функций, дабы не засорять стек? Так же не рассматриваю вариант поставить во втором таймауте 10000, а в третьем 15000, так как считаю это какими-то "костылями".

Answer (score 1):

Пример используя `promise`:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var status = $('#loading-banner h1');
        if(!status) return false;
        function f1() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    status.html('Авторизация в системе...');
                    resolve();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
        function f2() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    status.html('Получение информации...');
                    resolve();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
        function f3() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#loading-banner').fadeOut(1000);
                    resolve();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
        f1().then(function() {
            return f2();
        }).then(function() {
            return f3();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-banner">
    <h1>Статус ок</h1>
</div>
```